# How to digitalize photo without negatives?

Tags: scanning, photos

I was wondering which is the best way to aquire many photos that I have on film (for which I don't have negatives anymore) for my digital collection.

I was thinking about scanning them but I think this will generate many artifacts unless a specific way or specific settings exist for this purpose..

Does anyone have ideas regarding this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are these transparencies or prints? If they are transparencies you can use a negative scanner - which should have a sufficient resolution to avoid most artefacts.

Comment: unfortunately they are prints.. I don't know if there's a way to tweak up scanning to remove this kinds of artifacts.. I really would like to digitalize my old photos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to spend hours in front of a home scanner manually trying to scan all your photo's with the correct alignment, position, resolution, etc, why not have someone else do it for you?

A service that I stumbled upon was [ScanDigital](http://www.scandigital.com/). For $0.68 USD per photo at 600 dpi (seems kind of low though...), you can get them digitized very easily. Something worth considering